# How to encrypt with Kernel AES?

Tags: linux, kernel, aes

Linux Kernel contains many cryptographic algorithms including AES-CBC. 
I've found AES code in Kernel source code and I want to test it using some standard vectors I found in book called `The Design of Rijndael`.
so, is there any way to MANUALLY use it for encrypting specific strings, besides re-compiling the code and making executable file?

> Note: I'm not taking about using OpenSSL OR other tools, those tools are already have their AES and it's in user space.

thanks

Comment: Have a look at AF_ALG. There is an example of AES encryption here : http://lwn.net/Articles/410833/ . Side note: there is a plugin for OpenSSL relying on AF_ALG hence OpenSSL can perform crypto operations in the kernel.

Comment: I don't want OpenSSL to work in kernel space, I want to use AES of the kernel.
Kernel's AES is used for something like IPSec connections, I don't know how to access it from user-space

Comment: What is wrong with AF_ALG then?

Comment: It works on my box. Linux 3.18.5-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Jan 30 07:31:50 CET 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux